# Checking for null or character values in an if condition in shell script

Tags: shell, unix, if-statement, null, sh

I am trying to combine two conditions that checks for character values or a null value.  For some reason they only work separately, when I try to combine them together in an "or" it gives me errors.  Am I missing something?

```
RETENTION= #either a character value or null value
if [[ "$RETENTION" == +([a-zA-Z]) ]] || [ -z "$RETENTION"] ; then
 #bad input
 #exit 1
```

using an elif to do it separately will not work either.  Only one condition works.

Comment: What errors are you getting? Also, what do you have after `then`?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You have a typo in your condition:

```
if [[ "$RETENTION" == +([a-zA-Z]) ]] || [ -z "$RETENTION" ] ; then
```

Should be:

```
if [[ "$RETENTION" == +([a-zA-Z]) ]] || [ -z "$RETENTION" ] ; then
```

You had the double square bracket closed before your OR conditio

UPDATE
Actual resolution is to swap the order of the conditions:

```
if [ -z "$RETENTION" ] || [[ "$RETENTION" == +([a-zA-Z]) ]]  ; then
```

Comment: I get an error when i tried the the corrected line.

I get this message 

shellscript.sh[161]: 0403-057 Syntax error at line 161 : `]' is not expected.

Comment: I am not in a position to actually test it, but the brackets don't look like they properly balanced. Try wrapping both conditions in double square brackets with the OR between them.

Comment: I flipped the two conditions and it seems to work.  

[ -z "$RETENTION" ] || [[ "$RETENTION" == +([a-zA-Z]) ]]

Thanks for the help

Comment: There is not difference between the typo code and the "should be" code!